# Java Application Deployment Best Practices

Tags: java, server, architecture

I have a few small Java interfaces that either make web service calls or read/write files for FTP interaction. None of the applications accept incoming requests, rather their execution is scheduled periodically. Right now, I am simply creating a project directory on the application server, with src/bin/lib/res directories beneath.

```
java
    MyProject1
        src
        bin
        lib
        res
    MyProject2
        src
        etc...
```

I transfer the .java source file to the src directory, then compile the .class file to the bin directory. Once the binary is created, I can call it to execute the program. It works fine as is.

However, my question is, is this how I should be deploying & structuring my Java applications on the server? Should I be deploying an executable jar? Should I be doing something else entirely? I feel pretty comfortable with Java development, but have no real experience in deployment/architecture.

Comment: Deploying an executable JAR would be easier.  Do you ever retrieve the source code from the server, or do you maintain the source code somewhere else?  Here's one article I found, [Best Practices for Java Deployments](https://dzone.com/articles/best-practices-for-java-deployments) to help you get started.

Comment: I maintain the code on my PC using Eclipse, then transfer the files to the server to compile.